# Cancel ASIHTTPRequest from NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest, nsoperationqueue

My question is whenever I try to cancel the `ASIHTTPRequest` which is added in `NSOperationQueue`, nothing happens it calls the delegates and don't stop, i used the following code:

`[request cancel];`

`[request clearDelegatesAndCancel];`

But seems to be not working.

**My Code:**

```
[operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

    AsyncCallerClass *asyncClass=[[AsyncCallerClass alloc] init];
    DataSet *ds=[[DataSet alloc]init];
    asyncClass.MethodParameters=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    asyncClass.req=cusRequest;
    asyncClass.mehtodName=@"testMethod";
    asyncClass.xmlNameSpace=@"http://test.org/";
    asyncClass.xmlURLAddress=@"http://myPC/service.asmx";
    NSMutableData *data;
    data=[asyncClass getDataFromWebService];
    [ds parseXMLWithData:data];

    NSMutableDictionary *Data_Dictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[ds getRowsForTable:@"DataTable"] ];

    currRow=[Data_Dictionary objectForKey:@"0"];

}];
```

Now in AsyncCallerClass Class

```
ASIHTTPRequest *myRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[myRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[myRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];

[myRequest addRequestHeader:@"SOAPAction" value:self.SOAPActionURL];

NSString *messageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[sRequest length]];

[myRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:messageLength];

[myRequest appendPostData:[sRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[myRequest setDelegate:self];

[myRequest setTimeOutSeconds:120];

[myRequest startSynchronous];
```

and to cancel it I call a method in AsyncCallerClass

```
-(void) cancelMe:(NSOperationQueue*) myQueue  
{

[myRequest cancel];

[myRequest clearDelegatesAndCancel];

}
```

Comment: try with this  `[request setDelegate: nil];` 
        `[request setDidFinishSelector: nil];`

Comment: paste some amount of code pl

Comment: I tried [request setDelegate: nil]; [request setDidFinishSelector: nil];, bt it is not helping either

Comment: try cancelAllOperations